# How to Add a New Item to filepickeruploader control in dotnetnuke?

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module, filepicker

I would like to add a new item to the file picker, but I do not know what to do.
I always see a directory portal\0\ 
How can I change or add path in filepickeruploader ?

```
<dnn:filepicker id="filepicker1" runat="server"></dnn:filepicker>
DnnFilePickerUploader filepicker = (DotNetNuke.Web.UI.WebControls.DnnFilePickerUploader)Panel1.FindControl("filepicker1");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the path by using the FilePath property.

For example, if you wanted to set the default folder to be "Images/", try this:

```
<dnn:FilePicker id="filepicker1" runat="server" FilePath="Images/"></dnn:FilePicker>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the DotNetNuke.Services.FileSystem namespace. To add a new folder would be:

```
FolderManager.Instance.AddFolder(PortalId, myPath);
```